# Gnome 3.14 system menu new button

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome3, gnome-shell

Just installed Gnome 3.14 on Arch. What's the function of this new button on system menu?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "rotation lock" button, for tablets and similar hardware. It shows up if gnome-settings-daemon has found at least one accelerometer device, marked by `ID_INPUT_ACCELEROMETER` in udev. (It might also show up

Run the following to list all devices marked as such:

```
udevadm trigger -v -n -p ID_INPUT_ACCELEROMETER=1
```

To manually disable the orientation plugin of gnome-settings-daemon:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
```

Comment: Thank you! I've disabled it now ... I think this is the HDD accelerometer ... but I have an SSD so I can ignore it :)